# JpaRepository find by manyToMany attribute

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, many-to-many

Let's imagine classic example of manyToMany relation. I have entities Student and Course and manyToMany relation table between those two entities.

```
@Entity
data class Student(
@Id
val id: UUID,
val name: String,
@ManyToMany
val courses: Set<Course>
)

@Entity
data class Course(
@Id
val id: UUID,
val title: String,
@ManyToMany
val students: Set<Student>
)
```

repository can looks like this:

```
@Repository
interface StudentRepository : JpaRepository<Student, UUID> {
   fun findAllByCoursesTitle(title: String): List<Student>
}
```

Function findAllByCoursesTitle should return all student signed up for math, for example.

My problem is:
**How will function looks like when i need to return all students signed up for two specific courses.** But i need it for dynamic number of courses, 1 or more.

for example input to function would looks like listOf("math", "geography") or in case of course_ids listOf("UUID", "UUID"). It does not matter if it will be ID or title. What is doalbe.

When i would want to write sql query for that it would looks like this:

```
SELECT student.id, sc1.course_id, sc2.course_id FROM student
JOIN student_course cs1
ON student.id = cs1.student_id
JOIN student_course cs2
ON student.id = cs2.student_id
WHERE cs1.course_id = ?
AND cs2.course_id = ?
```

But as i said, i need to have it done for various number of courses.

Please somebody advise.

Comment: Number of courses(ex: 2 course) or exact some courses(ex: math and english)? Show an example input-output to clear your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve logic at SQL statement you can try something like this:

```
SELECT st.id, sc.course_id, sc.course_id FROM student as st
JOIN (
    SELECT st.id as stId, sum(case when c.id IN (:courseIdList) then 1 else 0 end) as cc FROM student as std 
    JOIN student_course as cs ON std.id = cs.student_id 
    JOIN cource as c ON c.id = cs.cource_id
    GROUP BY (st.id) having cc >= :minimumCourseNumbers 
) A on A.stId = st.id
```

There're `courseIdList`: List course Ids. `minimumCourseNumbers`: Minimum course numbers that student must register.

However, I think the logic should move to application to filter.